# Approximate result for $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$?

Tags: approximation, infinite-product

What would be a quick way to approximately determine the value of

$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)=\phi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) , $$

where $\phi(q)$ is the [Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function)? By approximating, I mean determine the first few digits of the result starting from the product representation without additional knowledge of other properties of $\phi(q)$.

For instance, my non-programmable [CASIO fx-991ES](https://edu.casio.com/products/ntd/fx991es/) calculator comes with a summation function $\sum_n$, but no multiplication function $\prod_n$, so assuming that I have access to this low complexity piece of equipment, I got an approximation as

$$\begin{align}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right) &= \exp\left(\ln\left(\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\right)\right)\\
&\approx\exp\left(\sum_{n=1}^{100}\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\right)\\
&=0.2887880951\end{align}$$
by doing a finite sum and exponentiating the result instead. Curiously, all of the digits are correct, so maybe summing even fewer terms would be sufficient to get just a few digits right.

But what if all I have is paper and pen? Is there a way to get a good approximation in a few lines?

Comment: Since the relative error after $n$ factors is exponentially small in $n$, [the convergence is linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence#Q-convergence_definitions). Some [acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration) will be feasible, but there's only so well you can do without a computer.

Comment: @metamorphy Thanks, just a few terms of this do the job nicely!

Comment: @metamorphy Please give your comment as an answer. It is excellent and I will upvote it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quadratic convergence formula is given by the [pentagonal number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem) $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^n)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^n x^{n(3n-1)/2}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n(1+x^n)x^{n(3n-1)/2}.$$ The summation (at $x=1/2$) over $1\leqslant n\leqslant 10$ already gives over $50$ correct digits.

Answer (score 1):

Put
$$
p_{\;n}  = \prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left( {1 - {1 \over {2^{\,k} }}} \right)} 
$$

Then
$$
p_{\;n + 1}  = p_{\;n} \left( {1 - {1 \over {2^{\,n + 1} }}} \right)
 = p_{\;n}  - {{p_{\;n} } \over {2^{\,n + 1} }}\quad \left| {\;p_{\;1}  = {1 \over 2}} \right.
$$
which means that the $\{ p_n \}$ sequence is steadily decreasing, while remain positive, and thus converges.

Being steadily decreasing, at a decreasing absolute rate, you can multiply the first terms untill the required number of digits
become stable.

Answer (score 1):

$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)=\Bigg[\prod_{n=1}^p\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\Bigg]\Bigg[\prod_{n=p+1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\Bigg]$$

Fot the second product, take its logarithm
$$\log\Bigg[\prod_{n=p+1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\Bigg]=-\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2 x^2}+\frac{1}{3 x^3}+\frac{1}{4 x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)\right)$$ where $x=2^n$.

So, the *approximation* will write
$$\Pi_p=\frac {a_p}{b_p} \exp\left(- \frac {c_p}{d_p}\right) $$ Below are listed the various constants
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
p & a_p & b_p & c_p & d_p \\
 1 & 1 & 2 & 1229 & 2240 \\
 2 & 3 & 8 & 28087 & 107520 \\
 3 & 21 & 64 & 73229 & 573440 \\
 4 & 315 & 1024 & 1738567 & 27525120 \\
 5 & 9765 & 32768 & 4611629 & 146800640 
\end{array}
\right)$$ and now the numerical values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \text{result} \\
 1 & \color{red}{0.288}8615143 \\
 2 & \color{red}{0.2887}901234 \\
 3 & \color{red}{0.288788}1550 \\
 4 & \color{red}{0.28878809}69 \\
 5 & \color{red}{0.2887880951 }
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: This looks curious! I don't fully understand what you are doing, for the following reasons: 1) the definitions of $\prod_p,a_p,b_p,c_p,d_p$ in terms of the original problem statement are not given (an estimate of the complexity of their calculation would also be interesting), 2) no explanation on why we take the log of the partial product, why it results in that particular sum, and what it tells us.