# Is $\frac{2 \cdot 4\cdot 8 \cdot 16 \cdots}{1\cdot 3\cdot 7\cdot15 \cdots}$ irrational?

Tags: sequences-and-series, rationality-testing

The number is the infinite product:$$\frac{2 \cdot 4\cdot 8 \cdot 16 \cdots}{1\cdot 3\cdot 7\cdot15 \cdots},$$ or about $3.4628.$

I have only proven this number is finite. Can you either prove it is irrational or express it as a fraction with integer numerator and denominator?

Comment: So $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{2^i - 1}\right)$ right? Don't want anyone else to get confused :D

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: It is the reciprocal of this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4093369/42969.

Comment: Yes, it looks complicated... did anyone prove irrationality?

Comment: Also see [q pochhammer symbol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol)

Comment: It can be written as $$\prod_i\frac{1}{1-\frac1{2^i}}.$$ The function $f(z)=\prod_i\frac1{1-z^i}$ has a name, but I’m not having much luck recalling it. $f(z)$ is the generating function for the partition function.

Comment: For what its worth, proving irrationality is notoriously difficult for many numbers.  For instance, we don't even have a proof yet that $\pi+e$ is irrational so I for one wouldn't be surprised if this were an open problem still.

Comment: Ah, the function’s inverse is called Euler’s function. So your question is equivalent to whether $\phi(1/2)$ is rational. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function

Comment: Replying to JMoravitz:  I wondered whether that was the case but I thought maybe a genius would see it and find a proof\/(._.)/

Answer (score 7):

This is equivalent to whether $$\phi\left(\frac12\right)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac1{2^n}\right)$$ is rational, where $\phi$ is [Euler’s function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function)

But Euler’s function power series formula gives:

$$\phi\left(\frac12\right)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{1}{2^{(3n^2-n)/2}}$$

I think a certain amount of fiddling should show that this value does not have a repeating base $2$ expansion, so the value is not rational.

---

Basically, grouping $n=2k,2k+1,-2k,-2k-1$ for $k>0$ gives $$\phi(1/2)=q+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2^{6k^2-k}}+\frac{1}{2^{6k^2+k}}-\frac{1}{2^{6k^2+5k+1}}-
\frac1{2^{6k^2+7k+2}}\right)\tag1$$
where $q,$ the sum for $n=-1,0,1,$ is rational.

Now, for $m_2>m_1,$ $$\frac{1}{2^{m_1}}-\frac1{2^{m_2}}=\sum_{j=m_1+1}^{m_2}\frac1{2^j}$$

Then: $$\frac{1}{2^{6k^2+k}}-\frac{1}{2^{6k^2+5k+1}}-
\frac1{2^{6k^2+7k+2}}\\=\sum_{i=6k^2+k+1}^{6k^2+5k+1}\frac{1}{2^i}-\frac{1}{2^{6k^2+7k+2}}\\=\sum_{i=6k^2+k+1}^{6k^2+5k}\frac{1}{2^{i}}+\frac1{2^{6k^2+5k+1}}-\frac{1}{2^{6k^2+7k+2}}\\=\sum_{i=6k^2+k+1}^{6k^2+5k}\frac1{2^{i}}+\sum_{j=6k^2+5k+2}^{6k^2+7k+2}\frac1{2^j}$$

So the summand in $(1)$ is $$\frac{1}{2^{6k^2-k}}+ \sum_{i=6k^2+k+1}^{6k^2+5k}\frac1{2^{i}}+\sum_{j=6k^2+5k+2}^{6k^2+7k+2}\frac1{2^j}$$

Since $6(k+1)^2-(k+1)=6k^2+11k+5>(6k^2+7k+2)+1,$ these ranges of bits do not overlap, nor are even adjacent.

In particular, the locations of the $1$ bits surrounded by $0$ bits are at only the positions $6k^2-k,$ and thus the binary expansion does not repeat.

---

You can easily use the same proof to show that $\phi(1/b)$ is irrational for any integer with $b>1,$ using base $b$ arithmetic.

You can give a similar argument for $b<-1,$ but need a different grouping. Basically you need to group the eight terms for $k,k+1,$ when $k$ is even.

Comment: Thanks , I might have to look into the power series to understand this first...

Comment: Yeah, the power series result is not trivial.

Comment: Can you explain it in a way that might be intelligible to me ( I understand if not )? It doesn't seem to be on the linked page.

Comment: I didn't realise you edited your original comment..

Comment: It is definitely on the linked page. It is called “The Euler identity.” Or the  “pentagonal number theorem.” I’ve just written it out for $q=\frac12.$ @AmoebaProteus And no, I probably can’t explain it, sorry. Wikipedia’s page on the theorem gives a combinatorial proof. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem

Comment: Ah, I could have grouped $-2k, 2k+1,-(2k+1),$ and $2(k+1)$ for $k\geq 0$ to have gotten all the terms of $\phi(1/2).$